# Google-Chrome with Maps not printing at the right way

Tags: google-chrome, printing, maps

There is a problem detected only with Google Chrome when I try print a map (it cuts the map and there is a part of it which appears to be white, but it's loaded).

In this case, all is working with all browsers, but when I try with Chrome 31 and 32 it fails printing the appended map (despite of delays to be assure that it's loaded or "tilesloaded" trigger).

The current code which launchs print action is:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
    self.print();
});
```

Map is an object kind:

```
google.maps.Map
```

The [target page](http://test.archivesportaleurope.net/directory?p_p_auth=HP4ErzyI&p_p_id=directory_WAR_Portal&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&_directory_WAR_Portal_myaction=printEagDetails&_directory_WAR_Portal_id=545) provided by the [main page](http://test.archivesportaleurope.net/directory)

Has anybody an idea how it could being working?

I have tried converting the page to other formats.

Google was reported by nothing has done yet by his team.

Comment: Most probably this is not a reason but anyway. That page is full of tags with empty ids: `<script id="" src="http://...`

Comment: console.log: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://test.archivesportaleurope.net/Portal-theme/js/global.js`